# QtWebKit, QWebElement::setPlainText() problem

Tags: html, qt, qtwebkit, qwebelement

From Qt online [help](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qwebelement.html#setPlainText):

> ```
> void QWebElement::setPlainText ( const QString & text )
> ```
>
> Replaces the existing content of this
>   element with text. This is equivalent
>   to setting the HTML innerText
>   property.

My code:

```
QWebElement login = doc.findFirst("input[name=\"login\"]");
login.setPlainText("alibaba");
qDebug() << login.toPlainText();
```

And the output is "".
Why I don't see new value of login element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `input` html element doesn't have the closing tag so there's no sense in using methods that operate (set some content) in a space between the opening and the closing tag...
Besides, it's `value` **attribute** that should be set and not the content of the `input` element :)